# Getting more out of exchange rate

Tags: foreign-exchange, foreign-currency

Lately i been confused with the fact, when should one do a currency change. Here is a scenario,i am living as a expat in Uk, and i need to take out money from my international account from a another currency. The Uk currency show 155 day rate. Whereas by evening it became 145. IMO, if i do a change on 155, it would benefit me, but someone told me when the rate is less e.g 145. It would be more beneficial. TBH i don't understand how the maths work in this.?

Comment: It is absolutely impossible to guess whether it will go up or down.  If you think about it: that means you should always just do it with no hesitation: it makes absolutely no difference if you wait!

Answer (score 1):

If you are exchanging your foreign currency (US$) into GBP, then it will be better for you at 145 since you are paying less for each pound.

If you are changing your GBP into foreign currency, then it will be worse for you at 145 since you are receiving less for your pounds.

**EDIT**

With PKR the rate you are quoting is PKR per pound, so you would divide by 145.  Thus 10,000 PRK divided by 145 would give you about 69 pounds.

Using a rate of 155 you would receive PKR 10,000/155 = 64.5 pounds.

As you can see, you are better off at the 145 rate.

Comment: How does the maths work, if I may ask?

Comment: @Nofel  Are you buying or selling pounds?

Comment: Don't know how to answer that. I m withdrawing PKR rs and they get paid in pound. So I thinking its buying?

Comment: @Nofel  I will add an edit to my answer.  Please wait a minute for update....